# C++11 initialize map

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11

I am trying to initialize a STL map using C++11 syntax but that doesn't seem to work. After initialization, when i try to access the element, it tries to call the private constructor of Foo. Did I miss something? It works if I use at. I am wondering if I could use operator[] to access initialized values...

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Foo{
public:
    int a, b;
    Foo(int a_, int b_){
        a = a_;
        b = b_;
    }

private:
    Foo(){};
};


int main(){

    std::map<std::string, Foo> myMap = { {"1", Foo(10,5)}, {"2", Foo(5,10)} };
    int b  = myMap["1"].b;    // it tries to call private constructor of Foo.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you use the `operator[]` on a map, you may use the operator to either get a value from the map or assign a value into the map. In order to assign the value into the map, the map has to construct an object of its value type, and return it by reference, so that you can use `operator=` to overwrite an existing object.

Consequently, the type has to be default constructible so that a new object can be created for you to assign into.

At run time, the constructor won't be called if the key already exists, but the compiler has no way of knowing whether you'll ever use `operator[]` to access a value that doesn't exist, so it requires the constructor to be public.

Answer (score 20):

`operator[]` of map requires the type to be default constructible, because it creates a new entry if one doesn't exist.

You can use `at()` instead, which throws if the entry doesn't exist:

```
int b  = myMap.at("1").b;
```

Comment: The fact that it requires the constructor to exists does not mean that it should call it if the object already exist, which it shouldn't.

Comment: @David : C++11 does indeed require the `DefaultConstructible` concept for `map<>::operator[]` (§23.4.4.3/2,6).

Comment: True that... I was not thinking clearly and *read* that the constructor was actually *called*.

Comment: Couldn't you in theory have a const `operator[]` and SFINAE out the non-const version in case there's no default constructor? That would probably be thoroughly confusing, though; the new `at()` is clearly a better solution.

Comment: @JohannesD maybe. I think that's actually an interesting idea.